# How can I train my paranoid dog to NOT bark at every stranger she meets?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

We live in a shady neighborhood so we bought a big dog  (5 months old now) and have been training her to bark on command.  We haven't been doing this for long so she doesn't recognize the command unless I'm keeping a toy from her or vacuuming/sweeping/. . . .   However, I think we've made her a little paranoid.  We were on a walk yesterday and an elderly gentleman wanted to pet the "cute doggy"

Well despite my telling her "No" which she usually understands quite well.  our pup would not stop barking aggressively at him.  When we are in that situation again, **what can I do training wise to get her to stop barking at the friendly person?**

I would like her to still bark if say some one entered our yard or home unannounced.

Comment: Hi Dan! Feel free to check out the Q&A's that I have attached to your question, they have some really good advice that will be able to help you :)